# IOS: how to take picture of scanned barcode?

Tags: ios, swift, barcode-scanner

I am trying to capture the image of scanned bard code from camera and unable to find the way.

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {


for   metadata: AVMetadataObject in (metadataObjects as? [AVMetadataObject])!{
            for   type: String in barCodeTypes {
                if  metadata.type == barcodeType
                {
                 //do something and break
                }
           }
}
```

This method is called when bar code scanned is success, I need to get UIImage of scanned barcode. Help me out with this.

Comment: look at this tutorial [https://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-reader-swift/](https://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-reader-swift/)

Comment: Are you asking to be able save the photo of the barcode?

Comment: @MwcsMac yes, I need to get the UIImage of scanned bar code

Comment: You are talking two different use of the camera at the same time. To take the picture you need to use an `UIImagePickerController` which is different from the barcode functions.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm very interested.

Answer (score 3):

You can add another output to the session, for example AVCaptureStillImageOutput and when qr is detected take a photo with the method captureStillImageAsynchronously.